# aspx page rendered as empty/blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, iis-10

i have deployed web application (asp.net webform) on IIS, but the index.apsx page shows as empty/blank in browser(Chrome/IE/Microsoft-Edge) and Mozila-firfox show as :

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost:90/index.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

**index.aspx** is login page as well as start page.
I have searched a lot but did not find solution that works for me.

**NOTE:** The html page shows fine after deployment. Also in VS-2012 the web application works fine.

Any help regarding this ? Let me know if you need web.config file or any other file that help you understand the problem. thanks

Comment: are you sure your IIS..do not have default page set?I mean IIS might be configured to show index.htm page (note the htm extension)....

Comment: IIS has list of default documents, but what i am saying is that when i open `index.htm` it works fine, at the same if i change the `index.htm` to `index.aspx` then it shows nothing. A blank page.

Comment: you can attach debugger to worker process see if you hit debugger? and show us the code of your aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Visual Studio 2013. My solution was disable the browser link by adding

```html
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

in web.config appSettings.